# IE7 last links not clickable

Tags: css, hyperlink, internet-explorer-7

I have been told that on these pages, the last 2 links are not clickable in IE7. I can't seem to see the problem, and not sure how to fix it. Is it a hasLayout problem?

http://www.thamesvalleypartnership.org/somethingbrilliant/ideas/visual
http://www.thamesvalleypartnership.org/somethingbrilliant/evidence

Any help, or point in the right direction to how to fix would be really appreciated.

Comment: Which two? Everything I've checked is clickable in IE 7.

Comment: I have been told that it is happening in IE7 on the last two links in the content area on every page in the site. e.g evidence page last 2 word documents, and visual - 2 downloadable docs

Comment: Those links work ok for me in IE 7. Has the user reporting tried another browser? If they haven't possibly they don't have Word and cannot open the downloads and are incorrectly reporting the problem.

Comment: It is strange, they have tried on 2 computers in their office and both come back with unclickable links in ie7 but fine in other browsers. I can't seem to get the same problem. Their browser details are MSIE 7.0 on Windows XP

Comment: I have found someone else who has the problem, it seems to be on certain ie7, the links aren't clickable. Anyone know a fix?

Comment: The links are not clickable on IE8 in compatibility mode. (which sends IE7 user agent)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `margin-bottom:100px` to `div` with id `random` and remove `div` with class `push` (it is in `random` `div`. I have not tested it with other browsers and other versions of IE.

Comment: Many Thanks for this answer, I think this has done the trick. Thank you for your help